# jqGrid search box display on top

Tags: jqgrid

I have two grids on the page, one is normal page and another is a modal dialogue. The modal dialogue grid has search feature. When i display search dialogue it is sometimes displaying below the modal dialogue. How can i display search dialog always on top? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I answered on the same question some time before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5689137/315935) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6155351/315935) for the old searching dialog of jqGrid and then I posted [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833721/315935) which demonstrates the solution which you can use now.

Comment: I used overlay:false. It solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function with your  Form id.

```
function DragFormCenter(id) {
$(id).css('top', 0);
$(id).css('right', 0);}
```