# JQGrid Dynamic Column and Search Query

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Suppose I have the following data:

```
Name        Month           Expense
----------  --------------  ----------
XYZ         February         10
XYZ         March            50
KLM         March            20
ABC         April            30
```

Following the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding) I have been able to create a JQGrid instance that has the "Expense" value represented in columns instead of rows. For example:

```
Name        Expense February     Expense March     Expense April
---------   -----------------    ---------------   --------------
XYZ         30,00                50,00             0,00
KLM         0,00                 20,00             0,00
ABC         0,00                 0,00              30,00
```

In the  `colModel` that I am dynamically building I am using the same `index` value for every 
dynamically added column so every search will be redirected automatically to the `Expense` field.

This works like a charme :)

Unfortunately in the search dialog the users does not see a single column to filter on the Expense field but he has the opportunity to filter for the columns called respectively `Expense February`, `Expense March` and `Expense April` which is a little bit confusing because he thinks that is going to filter not only for the `Expense` property but also for the `Month` property.

Is there any way to instruct the jqGrid plugin to hide those unwanted labels and using only a generic field called `Expense`?

Thanks a lot for helping!

**EDIT:**

This is the generated object coming back from the first call (it contains colNames and colModel)

```
{
   "ColNames":[
      "Name", "Expense February", "Expense March", "Expense April"
   ],
   "ColModel":[
      { "name":"Name", "index":"Name", ... },
      { "name":"Expense1", "index":"Expense", ... },
      { "name":"Expense2", "index":"Expense", ... }, 
      { "name":"Expense3", "index":"Expense", ... }
   ]
}
```

Also this is the code that create the grid

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://server/GetColumns',
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            var colM = result.ColModel;
            var colN = result.ColNames;

            grid.jqGrid('GridUnload');

            grid.jqGrid({
                url: 'http://server/GetData',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'post',
                colModel: colM,
                colNames: colN,

                [other params here]
            })
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       [...]
    },
    complete: function () {
       [...]
    }
});
```

Comment: could you post which `colModel` you use for both grids.

Comment: Do you want to implement searching on the server or you use `loadonce: true` and want to use searching on the client side?

Comment: Hello Oleg, the search is implemented on the server and I am generating the `colModel` exactly as in the sample link provided. The sequence is: first I am doing an ajax call which return an object that has two arrays (colNames and colModel). On success I am unloading the grid and then recreate it using the data received from the previous call. Please let me know if you need further details...

Comment: I understand that you get `colModel` from the server, but which properties exactly you use. You wrote about the same `index` value, but I don't full understand how exactly the final settings look like. So it would be better to see `colModel` returned from the server.

Comment: Ok. Please have a look at my question EDIT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can just include `search: false` in all `ExpenseX` columns excepted the column `Expense1`. In the case the searching dialog will contains only one 'Expense' column for searching.

**UPDATED**: If you use Advanced Searching Dialog you can change the "Expense February" to "Expense" with respect of the [afterRedraw](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) callback:

```
afterRedraw: function () {
    $(this).find("table.group td.columns option[value=Expense1]").text("Expense");
}
```

In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangeFiledNameInSearchingDialog.htm) I change the standard "Client" name which come from `colNames` to the text "!!! My Client Name !!!":

[image]

The code of `afterRedraw` in the demo is longer only because I used [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchOnEnter1.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9659066/315935) as template. It allows additionally use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start the searching.

Comment: Yes you are right and I have already tried to do this. But unfortunately in the search dialog I will have the field `Expense February` wich is still confusing for the user. For this reason I was looking for a different way :)

Comment: @Lorenzo: It's not a problem. I'll post a workaround. You just wrote about searching and it was unclear which one you used. In case of Toolbar Searching for example you have no problem with the field name.