# How to make jqGrid Search when enter key is pressed in the find dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have followed the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027331/2920067) but I have not been able to make it work. I'm using the free-jqGrid version 4.9.0. I don't get any JavaScript errors either. While debugging I see the control just passed over the `click` method call and nothing happens.

Would appreciate any help,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of usage free jqGrid 4.9 you need just specify `searchOnEnter: true` option. You can use `searching` option of jqGrid to specify searching option used for both searching dialog of searching toolbar. For example

```js
searching: {
    closeAfterSearch: true,
    closeAfterReset: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    searchOnEnter: true,
    multipleSearch: true
}
```

See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods).